# Not able to read gradle.properties in jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

i am running jenkins pipeline job with gradle. I have a requirement to get the the property value mentioned the gradle.properties, how can i get it

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you need to read a property from file `gradle.properties` in a Jenkins pipeline script?

Comment: yes . i need to read property values from gradle.properties in jenkins declarative pipeline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Jenkins declarative pipeline built-in [readFile()](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) to read files from the workspace.

Let's say your `gradle.properties` contains

```
version=1.2.3-SNAPSHOT
```

To read the `version` property from the file do this in your `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage("read file from workspace") {
            steps {
                checkout scm

                script {
                    String content = readFile("gradle.properties")

                    Properties properties = new Properties()
                    properties.load(new StringReader(content))

                    echo "property 'version' has value '${properties.version}'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might fail when executed due to missing permission to execute arbitrary code, depending on your Jenkins setup. You'll may receive errors like this:

```
Scripts not permitted to use method java.util.Properties load java.io.Reader. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
```

Read more about this topic here: [Script Approvals](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/#script-approval).

Once approved, the property can be read in:

```
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
20:55:16 property 'version' has value '1.2.3-SNAPSHOT'
```

Answer (score 1):

Better solution without extra permission is simple

> [readProperties  - Pipeline Utility Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/)

```
script {
  def props = readProperties  file:'rest-api/gradle.properties'
  env.APP_VERSION = props['version']
}
```